# Why does it create an empty list()

Tags: python, list, generator

Sorry I am newbie here using Datacamp:

Python Version 3.7.3 on Windows
Using list(generator) creates an empty list

```
result = (num for num in range(10))

print(list(result))
```

**Actual Output:**

```
[]
```

**Expected Output:**

```
[0, 1, 2, 3..., 9]
```

Comment: It does not. Could you paste the exact things you ran ? That's a `set`, not a `dict`ionary. Also, i assume that is a typo for the `set comprehension` ?

Comment: What version of python are you using? `{num for num in range(10)}` creates a set containing numbers 0-9.

Comment: Either you didn't ran those exact two lines in sequence, or you are using some other `result`. Did you do anything with the `result` before using it in `list(result)` ?

Comment: I tried changing the assigned variable from 'result' to something else 'test' in this case, but output still an empty list [ ]...

Comment: Are you doing anything else with the result? Like, consuming it in another constructor?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

It works good in py3. You are creating a set not a dictionary. Dictionary should have keys and value. Also we can split the dictionary in to two lists one with keys and other with values. [image]

Comment: There is a simple rule here on Stack Overflow: no screenshots of code. Post it as code-formatted text.

Answer (score 0):

I think the line 2 should look like:

```
result = [num for num in range(10)]
print(result)
```

Comment: There is no mistake in OP's logic. It's working fine.

Comment: While that is more efficient than creating the list from a dict, the OP problem is that the comprehension returns an empty container. Swapping the comprehension type would just return a 6 empty container of different type.

Comment: I could do as you pointed out, however, I am trying to find the difference between generator and list. I made a mistake on the original post, it was supposed to be a generator and not a dictionary